# jQuery cookies and .each() help requested

Tags: jquery, cookies, each

Hi I'm using the jquery-cookies plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) and it's great for setting and deleting cookies when I know what they are.

What I'd like to accomplish is to have my script read all currently extant cookies and for each cookie that exists, do something.  What I'm using now looks like this:

--

```
// set some dummy cookies
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
$.cookie('2', '2_value');
$.cookie('3', '3_value');
$.cookie('4', '4_value');

// this returns a "cookie_value" alert, so I know the above cookies are set and scripts are properly included:
alert($.cookie('cookie_name')); // debug (working)

// for each cookie found, check the input with the same id - then pop an alert, just to debug
$.cookie(i,v).each(function(v) {
    $('input#' + v + ').attr('checked', true);
    alert(v); // debug (not working)
});
```

--

... but that .each statement doesn't do squat.  It's probably a matter of syntax but the documentation for the cookie plugin doesn't cover this well.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thank you in advance and please let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

You have extra quote:

```
$('input#' + v + ').attr('checked', true);
problem----------^
```

Should be:

```
$('input#' + v).attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: I like your method for pointing out the extra quote i will use this in the future +1 for formatting! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
// set some dummy cookies
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
$.cookie('test', 'woot');    

$.each($.cookie(), function(i, v) {
    alert(i + " = " + v); // outputs "cookie_name = cookie_value" etc.
});
```